# ReactNative TCP Socket

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sockets

I'm trying to updates states using RN TCP Socket library : https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-tcp-socket

But when i received data, state is not updated (Log is correctly displayed).

```
const App = () => {
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState('Init');
  const [numberMessage, setNumberMessage] = useState(0);

  const sendMessage = val => {
    // client.emit('data', {message: val});
    console.log(numberMessage);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    client.on('connect', () => {
      setConnected('Connected');
    });

    client.on('data', async data => {
      const increment = numberMessage + 1;
      await setNumberMessage(increment);

      console.log('received');
    });

    return () => {
      client.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 25}}>{connected}</Text>

        <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>{numberMessage}</Text>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => sendMessage('yes')}>
          <Text>Send message</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

I can't find a solution. Have you some tips or alternatives ?

Comment: Have you tried removing the async/await from your hook?

Comment: Yes, at start, async/await was not here. It was a try to fix my problem.